# Update embedded subdocument in array with doctrine and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, document

I want to update (replace) a subdocument within an array of all the documents, that have this specific embedded subdocument.

My sample **content** object is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51f289e5345f9d10090022ef"),
    "title" : "This is a content",
    "descriptors" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51f289e5345f9d10090022f4"),
            "name" : "This is a descriptor",
            "type" : "This is a property"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51f289e5345f9d10090022f0"),
            "name" : "This is another descriptor",
            "type" : "This is another property"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find the object with a specific `descriptor._id`.
I want to replace the one subdocument with another one (respectivley with an updated version of the old object, but not necessarily with the same properties).

While this works well in [RoboMongo](http://robomongo.org/) / shell...

```
db.Content.update(
{
    'descriptors._id': ObjectId("51f289e5345f9d10090022f4")
},
{
    $set: {
        'descriptors.$': {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51f289e5345f9d10090022f4"),
            "name" : "This is the updated descriptor",
            "category" : "This is a new property"
        }
    }
},
{
    'multi': true
})
```

...and with the [plain php methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php)...

```
$descriptor = array();
$descriptor['_id'] = new \MongoID('51f289e5345f9d10090022f4');
$descriptor['name'] = 'This is the updated descriptor';
$descriptor['category'] = 'This is a new property';

$mongo = new \Mongo('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$database = $mongo->selectDB('MyDatabase');

$output = $database->selectCollection('Content')->update(
    array('descriptors._id' => $descriptor['_id']),
    array('$set' => array('descriptors.$' => $descriptor)),
    array("multiple" => true)
);
```

...it doesn't work with [Doctrine MongoDB ODM](https://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)...

```
$descriptor = array();
$descriptor['_id'] = new \MongoID('51f289e5345f9d10090022f4');
$descriptor['name'] = 'This is the updated descriptor';
$descriptor['category'] = 'This is a new property';

$query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Content')
->update()->multiple(true)
->field('descriptors._id')->equals($descriptor['_id'])
->field('descriptors.$')->set($descriptor)
->getQuery()->execute();
```

...because it fails with the following error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\MyProject\vendor\doctrine\mongodb-odm\lib\Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Persisters\DocumentPersister.php line 998

So I assume, that *Doctrine MongoDB ODM* needs three parts in the dot-notation. The not so nice solution would be to iterate over the properties of the subdocument and set them manually.

```
$descriptor = array();
$descriptor['_id'] = new \MongoID('51f289e5345f9d10090022f4');
$descriptor['name'] = 'This is the updated descriptor';
$descriptor['category'] = 'This is a new property';

$query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Content')
->update()->multiple(true)
->field('descriptors._id')->equals($descriptor['_id']);
foreach ($descriptor as $key => $value) {
    $query->field('descriptors.$.'.$key)->set($value);
}
$query->getQuery()->execute();
```

But this will only **update existing** and **add new properties**, but **won't remove old/unnecessary properties** from the subdocument.

Any ideas how to solve the problem:

- with a simple query
- while using *Doctrine MongoDB ODM*
- without looping over the subdocument-array in php

I'm using:

- Mongo-Server: 2.4.5
- PHP: 5.4.16
- PHP-Mongo-Driver: 1.4.1

Composer:

```
"php": ">=5.3.3",
"symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
"doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in ODM and should be fixed in [PR #661](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/661). Please take a look and ensure that the revised test satisfies your use case.

Until the next beta of ODM is tagged, this will only reside in the master branch; however, that should match your `1.0.*@dev` version requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this thing but in a "not easy" way becuse when you use **EmbedMany** or **ReferenceMany** in Doctrine becames a [Doctrine **ArrayCollection**](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html) objects that implemented the [ArrayCollection **contains()**](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html#_contains) method with (as explained [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/source-class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html#215)) with the  [PHP **in_array()**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) method with the **$strict** parameter set to **true**... this way works with ReferenceMany but not with EmbedMany!

The concept is: ArrayCollection -> array -> ArrayCollection

In the definition of Document
...

```
/**
 * @ODM\EmbedMany(targetDocument="EmbeddedElement")
 */
private $elements = array();

...

public function getElements() { return $this->elements; }
public function setElements($elements) { $this->elements = $elements; }
public function addElement(Element $element) { $this->elements[] = $element; }

public function setElement(Element $element, $index=0)
{
    $elementsArray = $this->elements->toArray();

    $elementsArray[$index] = $element;

    $this->elements = new ArrayCollection($elementsArray);
}

public function removeElement(Element $element)
{
    $index = array_search($element, $this->elements->toArray(), $strict=false);

    if($index !== false)
        $this->elements->remove($index);
}

public function removeElementByIndex($index) { $this->elements->remove($index); }
```